# python regex for people names

Tags: python, regex

hello i have tried to extract all the names from the following string:

```py
import re
def Find(string):
    url = re.findall(r"[A-Z][a-z]+,?\s+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\.?\s*)?[A-Z][a-z]+", string)
    return url
string = 'Arnold Schwarzenegger was born in Austria. He and Sylvester Stalone used to run a restaurant with J. Edgar Hoover.'
print(Find(string))
```

but i have got a problem with the output(doesnt print the J. on edgar)

```
['Arnold Schwarzenegger', 'Sylvester Stalone', 'Edgar Hoover']
```

another question for you :)
i have tried to print the second string but i get a problem.
i need to write a regex that print it without www or http or https like in the example:

```py
import re
def Find(string):
    url = re.findall(r'https?://[^\s<>"]+|www\.[^\s<>"]+', string)
    return url
string = 'To learn about pros/cons of data science, go to http://datascience.net. Alternatively, go to datascience.net/2020/'
print(Find(string))
```

output is:

```
['http://datascience.net.']
```

thanks

Comment: Try to keep it one question at a time, please.

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1

Here's a regex that works for that specific case of three names:

`((?:[A-Z]\.\s)?[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+)`

yields

```
Arnold Schwarzenegger
Sylvester Stalone
J. Edgar Hoover
```

## Question 2

`(?:http)?s?(?:\:\/\/)?(?:www.)?([A-z]+\.[A-z]+(?:[\./][A-z0-9]+)*\/?)`

yields

```
http://datascience.net
datascience.net/2020/
```

Comment: hi! i meant that i want to print all the urls both with http and without(all the urls in this string) thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a beefier regex for #2.